# Wordpress - Static Front Page, and Blog Post - Custom template?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know some solutions to this, but I feel like I'm always taking a wrap around way.  Whats the easiest way to get Wordpress to route to the appropriate pages / templates:

I have a PAGE called 'News & Events'.  I want that to be my 'Posts Display' page (but not the front page)

I have a static 'Home' page that I want to be the 'Front Page', but I want it to use its own template, not 'page.php'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the slug for your page is "home", name your template file "page-home.php" and that will be used by Wordpress. Change the front page to be your home page under Settings > Reading.

Use [this handy chart](http://digwp.com/2010/02/template-heirarchy-chart/#more-1431) to see how wordpress determines which template to use.